# CSS on login page does not take effect after wordpress setup

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-login

My WordPress version is 6.2.2, and PHP version is 8.2.3.

After WordPress is installed, the login page looks like this:

> [image: chrome inspect screenshot]

I checked the login button, but no CSS was assigned to it. CSS links in the head section can be accessed by the way.

> [image: chrome inspect screenshot]

Not only the login page, but when I installed a theme(Avada), the theme setup page also looks wired. It is ok if only the login page is since I can still log in. But I can not use the theme because the theme setup page is totally messed up.

This really frustrated me, any help is appreciated.

I tried different WordPress and PHP versions (version 6.0.5 and version 7.4.2 respectively) and had the same problem.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Avada has changed something, now they’re retrieving data with another parameter as well, ‘builder’ and builder_id, not just fb-edit. These page builders keep everybody busy

Because of this, the cookie blocker was loaded in the builder mode, which should not be the case.

The below should resolve the issue (added as mu-plugin), or you can try this branch:https://github.com/Really-Simple-Plugins/complianz-gdpr/tree/avada-fix. Will get added to the plugin after it’s been tested and confirmed.

```
function rsp_my_add_new_avada($preview){
if ( isset( $_GET['builder_id'] ) ) {
    return true;
}
return $preview;
```

}
add_filter( 'cmplz_is_preview', 'rsp_my_add_new_avada' );